# SQL Server query with multiple joins

Tags: sql-server

I have a query to build with multiple joins. I would like to know which one is the best practice (fastest) between the 2 below. They both return the same result. Thank you

```
SELECT A.ID FROM RE7.DBO.RECORDS AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN [re7].[dbo].[ADDRESS] AS B ON A.ID=B.ID 
WHERE B.COUNTRY = 1670

SELECT A.ID FROM RE7.DBO.RECORDS AS A
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID FROM [re7].[dbo].[ADDRESS] WHERE COUNTRY = 1670) AS B
ON A.ID=B.ID
```

Comment: Both will have identical execution plan. If am not wrong there won't be any difference in performance. I will choose `INNER JOIN` as best practice for your requirement. `LEFT JOIN` should be used when you want non matching records from left table

Comment: Why not a simple `SELECT A.ID FROM RECORDS AS A
INNER JOIN [ADDRESS] AS B ON A.ID=B.ID 
WHERE B.COUNTRY = 1670` ? Unless I miss something, this one also should return the same result, and avoids the subqery. As you filter on b.Id, you don't care on b empty lines.

Comment: "Best practice" is to let the optimiser decide (imho).  Both of your queries should have the same execution plan, and the first version will "promote" the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` based on the fact that you have items from the "B" table in your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ID FROM RE7.DBO.RECORDS AS A
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID FROM [re7].[dbo].[ADDRESS] WHERE COUNTRY = 1670) AS B
ON A.ID=B.ID
```

INNER JOINS are almost always faster than `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.   `LEFT OUTER JOIN` takes the longest of all the joins.

You might not see a big difference in query time in this case, but INNER JOINS are best practice.